# Mudar 'class' quando mudar a view

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-3

Eu estou usando **bootstrap** e **angular**

Eu tenho um nav:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" ng-model="activeVar" style="margin-top:50px;">
            <li role="presentation"><a value="overview" ui-sref="main.admin.shops.single.overview">Übersicht</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a value="inventory" ui-sref="main.admin.shops.single.inventory">Produkte</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a value="orders" ui-sref="main.admin.shops.single.orders">Bestellungen</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a value="settings" ui-sref="main.admin.shops.single.settings">Einstellungen</a></li>
</ul>
```

Gostaria de **aplicar** a `class` `active` quando **certa opção** for selecionada. Como faria isso? Uso `angularjs` em meu sistema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a diretiva `ui-sref-active`, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active">
    <a value="overview" ui-sref="main.admin.shops.single.overview">Übersicht</a>
</li>
```